How to create dependent picklist on multeselect picklist?
How to create dependent picklist on multeselect picklist? If I selected other multiselect picklist then I have to show 'Existing' for others field.
Multi-Select
New
Old
Other
if other selected I have to show Existing as a option in front of the Others

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In Dependent Picklist Considerations, it is noted that:

Multi-select picklists can be dependent picklists but not controlling fields.

It is not possible to do this through configuration. You would need to write custom code in order to implement this.
